# Voice profile in Google Assistant

Tags: voice-recognition, google-assistant-sdk

Does Google Assistant provide individual voice identification, just like **voice profile** of Alexa?

Thank you

Comment: Have you googled the question?

Comment: Have you asked google about this? They created it.

Comment: Oh, I'll check it out! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Assistant does not provide user recognition as a core part of the platform or as part of the Assistant SDK.